# use datetime instead of datetime2 sqlserver hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, datetime, datetime2

I have hibernate configured as auto-update. I have a mssql-server 2012. Hibernate creates my java.util.Date objects as datetime2 in the database. Is there a possiblity to force hibernate to create datetime in the database?

I know that I can use annotations on the fields in my object, but there are too many. So I would like to configure hibernate, so that every java.util.Date becomes automatically datetime in the databse.

Comment: why do you need datetime?

Comment: other programs also use the database and can't handle with datetime2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing coming to my mind is defining a new Hibernate `Dialect`, which maps the Java data types to `datetime`, instead of the default `datetime2`.

A complete class example:

```
public class ModifiedSQLServerDialect extends SQLServer2008Dialect {
    public ModifiedSQLServerDialect () {
        super();
        registerColumnType( Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime" );
    }
}
```

If you look at the source of `SQLServer2008Dialect` (assuming Hibernate 4.3), you may see that the `Types.TIMESTAMP` is mapped to `"datetime2"`, we are effectively redefining it, in our own `ModifiedSQLServerDialect`.

**Using the new dialect**

To use the new dialect, we have just defined, you need to add the following property to the `persistence.xml` file:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.example.ModifiedSQLServerDialect" />
```